# Using 5wt suspension oil as lower leg bath

Tags: maintenance, suspension, lubricant

I did a lower leg service on my Rockshox Revelation RC3 2016.

Problem is when I added oil to the lower leg on re-assembly I used 5wt oil instead of 15wt oil.

Will the 5wt oil have enough lubricity to keep the forks from damage until I do them again in a couple of months or should I crack them open again and drop in some 15wt.

Id prefer to not cycle the crush washers if its a nice to have rather than needed.

Comment: I'd guess that the performance may be different enough that even if the lubrication and stuff are adequate, you may want to go with the manufacturer's recommended weight of oil.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, they're both shock oils and should have suitable shear strength and whatnot. I recently rebuilt a SID with 10wt and have had no problems. It's not unusual for people to tune their dampers using different oils, but that's another story.

Comment: Also, more than you ever cared to know about fork oil. http://www.peterverdone.com/wiki/index.php?title=Suspension_Fluid